# Is it possible to git reset as a new commit?

Tags: git

I'd like to reset a branch to a certain commit, but still keep its history. For example, given this branch:

> A -> B -> C

I'd like to create a new commit `A*` such that the branch at `A` and the branch at `A*` are exactly the same, and the history looks like:

> A -> B -> C -> A*

Is this possible in git?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can think of two approaches using `git revert`.

#### 1 - Revert, then squash

Revert the last two commits. This creates two new commits. I'm using the `--no-edit` flag here so it won't prompt you for a commit message for each revert.

```
git revert --no-edit HEAD^^..HEAD
```

Then, since you wanted one commit instead of two, do an interactive rebase to squash the two revert commits you just created.

```
git rebase -i HEAD^^
```

#### 2 - Revert with `--no-commit`, then commit

With the `--no-commit` flag, `git revert` does not commit anything, but just makes changes to the working tree and index.

```
git revert --no-commit HEAD^^..HEAD
```

Then you can commit the change.

```
git commit
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `git revert` for that. Read a nice [tutorial by Atlassian](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/resetting-checking-out-and-reverting).